# WinForms ContextMenu stays open when MenuItem is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contextmenu, .net-4.5

So I have a form DataGridView and when I right click on the grid I want to display a context menu that has one menu item in it. The menu item will open a second form that will provide some configuration options for the DataGridView.

Now all of this works absolutely fine, the context menu displays correctly and the second form opens correctly and all of the functionality on that form works correctly.

The only issue is that the context menu will only close if I click anywhere other than the menu item. No matter how many times I click on the menu item the context menu does not close.

I have tried looking for work arounds but as far as I can tell there is no way to programatically close the context menu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below are copies of the click events for opening the context menu and for the menu item click event.

```
private void DataGridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (dgv.CurrentCell == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Rectangle r = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);
            Point p = new Point(r.X + e.X, r.Y + e.Y);
            ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
            cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Item", Item_Click));
            cm.Show(dgv, p);
        }
    }
}

private void Item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new SecondForm().Show();
}
```

UPDATE:
I solved the issue by replacing the ContextMenu class with the ContextMenuStrip class, removing the MouseClick event handler and assigning the ContextMenuStrip object to DataGridView.ContextMenuStrip. It appears as though the ContextMenuStrip class deals with showing the menu when it's relevant control is right clicked, so if you add a click event handler to deal with opening the menu it will repeatedly try to render the menu making it flicker several times before it is eventually rendered

Comment: Nowhere in your code is there an attempt to hide the context menu. I'll try and cook something up, but you should either be saving the reference to the ContextMEnu you create in your form, or you can use the 'sender' variable, cast it as a ContextMenu, and try to Hide() it.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR I have tried various ways to hide the context menu but there doesn't appear to be an sort of hide function to call or visibility property to set. In previous applications I have built context menus automatically close when a menu item is clicked I can't figure out why it is not doing so here

Comment: Hard to guess what *other* code could cause the CMS to behave like that.  Always try the snippet you post yourself first to verify that it still misbehaves the same way.  Randomly, do favor the CellMouseUp event and the ContextMenuStrip class.

Comment: @HansPassant That's one problem solved! I swapped to using the ContextMenuStrip class and that seems to have fixed the issue, when I click the menu item the context menu now closes, so thank you for that! However using the ContextMenuStrip class causes what I can only describe as lag when showing the context menu, it jutters a lot before it eventually opens :(

Comment: You have other code that caused ContextMenu to misbehave,  That it does something wonky with ContextMenuStrip is not terribly surprising.  You can't get an answer for code we cannot see of course, posting a repro snippet is your burden.

Answer (score 0):

in your class add a private variable

```
private bool CloseMenu = true;
```

on mouse down of your Context Menu

```
private void Item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CloseMenu = false;
    new SecondForm().Show();
}
```

add context menu closing event

```
private void contextMenuStripMy_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !CloseMenu;
    CloseMenu = true;
}
```

Comment: So when I create my menu item like so:

`cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Item", Item_Click));`

Am I replacing the Item_Click method call with the closing event method call and putting the contents of the old method at the start of the closing event method?

Answer (score 0):

I found some workdaround on this problem after many trials.

Firstly, this is about ContextMenu and not ContextMenuStrip.

This is not perfect solution but it works good if you do not have other alternative solution.

Here is how.

Just Set Visiable = false for all MenuItems under the Context Menu.

Only one problem with this is that it shows small square around the mouse.

I think this small square is the empty context menu box.

However, this small square will be removed quickly if user clicks anywhere and if the context menu lose focus.

It is really small and not bothering.

In code, this will look something like this in case you have only one menu item.

```
                 if (cm != null)
                {
                    if (cm.MenuItems.Count > 0) cm.MenuItems[0].Visible = false;
                }
```

If you have multiple of items, then just loop through all menu items.

```
                 if (cm != null)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < cm.MenuItems.Count ; i++)
                     cm.MenuItems[i].Visible = false;
                }
```

Hope this helps.

It worked for my case.

So I did not have to swtich to ContextMenuStrip from ContextMenu.